# finding the index of num1 inside num2

Tags: c, indexing

Trying to write a code that finds the location (index) of one number inside another.
For example, num1=1948 , num2=94
the index will be 2.
Can some one please tell me what i did wrong?
thank you!

```
int num1, num2, index=0;
printf("Please enter a number: \n\n");
scanf_s("%d", &num1);
printf("\n\nPlease enter another number: \n\n");
scanf_s("%d", &num2);
int temp1 = num1;
int temp2 = num2;

while (temp1 != 0 || temp2 != 0)
    if (temp1 % 10 == temp2 % 10)
    {
        temp1 = temp1 / 10;
        temp2 = temp2 / 10;
        index++;
    }
    else temp1 = temp1/10;

if (index != 0)
    printf("%d\n\n\n", index);
else printf("no");



system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Do you want it for just one digit or more for ex : num1=1948 , num2=9 , Index=2 occurencess

Comment: Building on what @SelakaN said, your algorithm gives an index of 2 even for num1 = 1948 and num2 = 294. What you are looking for is a pattern matching algorithm. Look at algorithms like Knuth-Morris-Pratt (KMP).

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way to find out what's wrong in your code is to debug it, using a debugger or just adding some `printf` in your code. For example, you can print out the values of `temp1`, `temp2` and `index` every time you (re)enter the `while` loop. i.e.

```c
while (temp1 != 0 || temp2 != 0) {
    // Add this to find out what the values are in these variables
    printf("temp1=%-6d, temp2=%-6d, index=%2d\n", temp1, temp2, index); 

    if (temp1 % 10 == temp2 % 10)
    {
        temp1 = temp1 / 10;
        temp2 = temp2 / 10;
        index++;
    }
    else
    {
        temp1 = temp1/10;
    }
}
```

What I can see so far is that when there is an unmatch of `temp1 % 10` and `temp2 % 10`, the `temp2` variable is not being reset to the value `num2`. For example if you have `temp1 = 12323` and `temp2 = 123`, the states would be as follow:

```
|--temp1--|--temp2--|--index--|
| 12323   | 123     | 0       |
| 1232    | 12      | 1       |
| 123     | 1       | 2       |
| 12      | 1       | 2       | <-- You would want temp2 to reset to 123 and
| 1       | 1       | 2       |     compare again
| 0       | 0       | 3       |
```

PS: The [KMP](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kmp-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/) algorithm is doing this job, in string (char array)

Comment: changed my conditionts..
now it works almost perfectly, except cases where im eneterin odd digits number like 255 and it cant fint 25..
while (temp1 != 0)
 {
  if (temp1 % 10 == temp2 % 10)
  {
   temp1 = temp1 / 10;
   temp2 = temp2 / 10;
   index++;
   if (temp2 == 0 && temp1 >= 0)
   {
    printf("index is %d\n\n", index);
    break;
   }

  }
  else {
   temp1 = temp1 / 10;
   temp2 = num2;
   index++;


  }

 }
 if (temp1 == 0 && temp2 > 0)
  printf("-1\n\n");

Comment: @KfirBilu Okay, first codes in comment is very unreadable. Try edit your post and add the codes as an Update, as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39264/579775)