# Check if 1st number contains 2nd number

Tags: c

I get 2 numbers. I should print whether the first one contains the second. If it does, print its matching location from the right (first location is `0`), if not - print `-1`. For example, `52335` contains `335` with location `2`, but `4554` does not contain `44`.

This is the code I tried, but it does not do the job

```
int main () {
    int location, position = -1;
    int number1, number2;
    printf("Please enter number 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &number1);
    printf("Please enter number 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &number2);

    int temp1 = number1, temp2 = number2;
    for (temp1 = number1; temp1 > 0; temp1 /= 10) {
        location = position++;
        for (temp2 = number2; temp2 > 0; temp2 /= 10) {
            if (temp1%10 != temp2%10) {
                location = -1;
                break;
            }
            else {
                temp1 /= 10;
                location++;
            }
        }
        if (location != -1) break;
    }

    printf("%d\n", location);
}
```

**without using help functions**

Comment: what is a help function?

Comment: @Hogan for example, a function that returns the digit of number in  `n` location

Comment: I assume scanning the input as characters is forbidden. Otherwise this problem would be solved in three lines of code. You should make this clear.

Comment: That still does not make it clear Tal -- since an important part of a language is the standard library -- are you saying the standard library can't be used?  (But I see scanf and printf) --- Which parts of the standard C library can't be used? -- how do I know what a helper function is?  As Marco points out, this is simple using standard library functions.  Why can't we use those?  What exactly are the requirements?

Comment: Convert both integers to strings using `sprintf`.  Search for one string in the other using `strstr`.  That's really the only reasonable way to do it.

Comment: @Hogan For example, Can't use the solution above. Can use basic functions like `printf` , `scanf`.. The solution must involve nested `for` loop

Comment: That kind of unexplained requirements usually indicate a homework assignment. Is this one?

Comment: @Yunnosch It is.

Comment: I can't believe this is a real world problem -- this is an assembly instruction (SCA) that does this so it makes sense for application to use the library function that does it at the CPU level.  This mush be homework or something like that -- there is no real world application of this question.

Comment: @Hogan it is HW

Comment: strstr is the most basic of function -- it converts directly to an asm instruction

Comment: @Hogan I'm aware of this function, but I need to solve this question without using this function. Nested `for` loops is required.

Comment: If you really want to do it without strstr it seems your code is working fine. But it will stop working for integers larger than INT_MAX (2147483647). Is that the issue you are having?

Comment: @hko This is not the issue. For the input: number1: `885`, number2: `88` - I get `-1`. But I cannot find the problem

Comment: I just tried your code with 885 and 88, I get 2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this according to @hko

Comment: @hko Try this one: N1 = 34337 , N2 = 43. It prints -1.

Comment: @TalRofe [I tried too](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EaTryXbA7slneNXO), it prints 4. Could you please check if the code you are executing is the same that you posted?

Comment: @Tal Rofe please edit your question that you want to do this task without using strstr. That makes it clear right away instead of reading through comments.

Comment: Are you two friends? This is 99% similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009753/finding-the-index-of-num1-inside-num2/59010466).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no sprintf only loops
https://godbolt.org/z/sfYJJh

```
char *myrevitoa(int number, char *buff)
{
    char *start = buff, *tmp = buff;
    while(number)
    {
        *buff++ = (number % 10) + '0';
        number /= 10;
    }
    *buff-- = 0;
    return tmp;
}

int is(int x, int y)
{
    char numbers[2][12];
    myrevitoa(x, numbers[0]);
    myrevitoa(y, numbers[1]);

    return !!strstr(numbers[0], numbers[1]);
}

int main()
{
    int haystack = 12345678;
    int neadles[] = {123, 321, 12345678, 1, 567};

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(neadles) / sizeof(neadles[0]); i++)
        printf("is %d part of %d? %s\n", neadles[i], haystack, is(haystack, neadles[i])  ? "YES" : "NO");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ZAF_wY

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int is(int x, int y)
{
    char numbers[2][12];
    snprintf(numbers[0], sizeof(numbers[0]), "%d", x);
    snprintf(numbers[1], sizeof(numbers[1]), "%d", y);

    return !!strstr(numbers[0], numbers[1]);
}

int main()
{
    int haystack = 12345678;
    int neadles[] = {123, 321, 12345678, 1, 567};

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(neadles) / sizeof(neadles[0]); i++)
        printf("is %d part of %d? %s\n", neadles[i], haystack, is(haystack, neadles[i])  ? "YES" : "NO");
}
```

Comment: Corner cases: `myrevitoa(y, 0]);` forms `""`, not the expected `"0"`.  `myrevitoa(y, some_negative_value);` is also problematic.  Looks OK for positive values.

Comment: `while(number)
    {
...    }` to `do    {
...    } while(number);`  fixes the 0 problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay now I see what your issue is. You need to introduce another variable instead of modifying the temp1 variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main () {
    int location, position = -1;
    int number1 = 34337, number2 = 43;
    int temp1 = number1, temp2 = number2, temp3;
    for (temp1 = number1; temp1 > 0; temp1 /= 10) {
        location = position++;
        temp3 = temp1;
        for (temp2 = number2; temp2 > 0; temp2 /= 10) {
            if (temp3%10 != temp2%10) {
                location = -1;
                break;
            }
            else {
                temp3 /= 10;
                location++;
            }
        }
        if (location != -1) break;
    }

    printf("%d\n", location);
}
```